# Calculus Question: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\sin(x)\ln{\sin{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble to compute

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\sin(x)\ln{\sin{x}}$$

I tried to find this limit using Wolfram Alpha and the result is 0, but I don't know how to get this 0.

Comment: I think it is so because $ \sin(x) $ will become $ 0 $ no matter what.

Comment: Think about the limit of $y \log(y)$

Comment: @hjpotter92 This is not sufficient.  $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$, but $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x) = 0$.  Instead, you could use L'Hopital's Rule to conclude that the desired limit is indeed $0$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm sorry, I can't figure it out your clue

Comment: @Venus. The same as Omnomnomnom gave as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we convert it to a quotient:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\sin{x}\ln{\sin{x}}}$$

And now we use the l'Hopital rule:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{\ln{\sin{x}}}{\frac{1}{\sin{x}}}}$$

...and now derive:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{(\ln{\sin{x}})'}{(\frac{1}{\sin{x}})'}}$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{\frac{1}{\sin{x}}\cos{x}}{-\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}}}}$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{\cot{x}}{-\frac{\cot{x}}{\sin{x}}}}$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{\sin{x}}}}$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{-\sin{x}}$$

...which is trivially $\underline{\underline{0}}$. Q.E.D.

Comment: @Zook You have right, I removed.

Answer (score 4):

If you believe/know $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} x\log(x)=0$ and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$  you are done:$$\sin(x)\log(\sin(x))=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}x\log(x\frac{\sin(x)}{x})=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}(x\log(x)+x\log(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}))$$

Comment: But limit x log x as x to 0 is indeterminate.

Comment: No $xlog(x)$ goes to $0$, if $x$ goes to zero. Log is to slow so to speak. It is a standard calculus result and  I bet you can find a proof somewhere on this community.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I upvote yours

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$
I=\lim_{x\to0}\sin (x)\ln\sin (x),
$$
then multiply $I$ by $\dfrac{\sin (x)}{\sin (x)}$ yield
$$
I=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin^2 (x)\ln\sin (x)}{\sin (x)}.
$$
Now we use L'Hôpital's rule and we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
I&=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2\sin (x)\cos(x)\ln\sin (x)}{\cos(x)}-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin^2 (x)\cdot\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin (x)}}{\cos(x)}\\
&=2I-\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)\\
I&=\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)\\
&=0.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

A more elementary argument:
$\sin(x)\ln\sin(x)=\ln(\sin(x)^{\sin x})$ and $\ln t$ is continuous at $t=1$. Here one only uses the fact that $y^y$ tends to $1$ when $y$ tends to $0$.

Comment: But 0^0 is indeterminate.

Comment: But $y^y$ is always well-defined and nonzero if $y>0$ so the indeterminacy is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Make a substitution.  Setting $u = \sin x$ (and noting the continuity of $\sin x$), we have
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)\ln(\sin(x)) = \lim_{u \to \sin(0)}u \,\ln u
= \lim_{u \to 0}u \,\ln u
$$
This is a standard problem usually done using L'Hôpital's rule.